# Trouble using setSelectedIndex: method in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I'm using a TabBar View with its controller.

in .h: `@interface TabsViewController : UITabBarController`

in .m:

```
#import "TabsViewController.h"

@interface TabsViewController () < UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate >

@end

@implementation TabsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    TabsViewController.setSelectedIndex:1; 
}
```

But last row give this error:

> "Property 'setSelectedIndex' not found on object of type
>   'TabsViewController'"

Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing selectedIndex property in wrong way.. I thinks you have created your own way 
to doing things in Objective-c. SelectedIndex in an instance Variable so you require same for setting/getting it.

Rewrite your `viewDidLoad` as follows...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.selectedIndex = 1; // or [self setSelectedIndex:1]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a reference of your UITabBar object from the UITabBarController and the method you will want to call is setSelectedItem:(UITabBarItem *)

```
UITabBar *bottomTabBar = self.tabBar;
[bottomTabBar setSelectedItem:[bottomTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]];
```